# Adding attributes from another dictionary for same key without overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6}
d2 = {'a': 5, 'c': 4, 'e': 8}
```

Iterating over the second:

```
for k, v in d2.items():
```

I would like to check for key presence in d1, and if it's there add that value as an attribute to the key and if not, add it to the dictionary so I want:

```
d1 = {'a': [2, 5], 'b': 4, 'c': [4, 5], 'd': 6, 'e': 8}
```

I know how to check for presence with the IN operator but can't work out how to update the dict with new attributes. 
Bear in mind, I have just presented a simple case of my problem and it will be within a loop which means a key could have multiple attributes rather than just 1 or 2.

Thank you.

Comment: Your output is not legal. Maybe you mean `... ,'a': [2,5], ...` ?

Comment: should that output be like `{'a': [2, 5], ...}`

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes, correct

Comment: Put all values as lists at start then it's trivial to do.

Comment: If, for some reason, you can't have lists as values at the beginning but can check whether a value is a list or not, then my answer will do the trick.

Comment: If my answer was satisfying, please don't forget to accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two values for one key in a dictionary. For that, you need the value to be a list to which you append the "real" values for that key.

```
for k,v in d2.items():
    if k in d1:
        if isinstance(d1[k], list):
            d1[k].append(v)
        else:
            d1[k] = [d1[k], v]

    else:
        d1[k] = v
```

However, this seems more straightforward:

```
for k,v in d2.items():
    if k in d1:
        d1[k].append(v)

    else:
        d1[k] = [v]
```

#### Update

Sum of the dictionary values, assuming the only thing you need is the total sum:

**Replace** above code with:

```
for k,v in d2.items():
    if k in d1:
        d1[k] = [sum(d1[k] + [v])]

    else:
        d1[k] = [v]
```

Comment: Yep latter option works perfectly for what I need it for. Cheers

Comment: How could I then sum the values within these lists for each key?

Comment: Not the total sum but the sum for each key. I have used your updated code but still having trouble with this.

I did: for k,v in d1.items():
             if len(qd[k]) > 1: 
                 d3 = {k:sum(qd[k])}

to firstly get the ones with multiple values but no luck

Comment: My updated answer does give the sum of the elements of the list value for each key.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thank you so much

Comment: Did you forget the brackets around `v`? At the line `d1[k] = [sum(d1[k] + [v])]`.

Comment: Apologies - had typed something wrong. Sorry to bother!

Comment: As a token of your gratitude, "upvote" my comments that helped you ;-)